# Check if text contains any string item from list of string c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to fetch a list of users after filtering by their name.

Query:

```
string filter="alex, faheem, Cohen";
var filterArr=filter.Split(new []{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(f=>f.Trim()).ToList();

var users= (from u in DbContext.Users
                where filterArr.Any(y=> u.Name.Contains(y)) select u);
```

This gives me the error:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

I can't use `filterArr.Contains(x.Name)` because Name column contains both first name and second name. Just Like in list above their is an item "alex" and I have a name "Alex Hales" combined in Name column. So If I use `filterArr.Contains(x.Name)` it will not give me the result.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: 1. make ToLower() before .Contains() (filterArr - all values should be lower)
filterArr.Contains(x.Name.ToLower())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible in a *single* statement like this.  It's too complicated for the poor parsing stuff to work out.

However, you can get an IQueryable(), then iterate over your filters append these as individual WHERE clauses, then these should get added to the SQL properly later.

Something like this:

```
//this just gets a reference the DbSet, which implements IQueryable<User>
var queryable = _dbContext.Users;

//iterate over the filters and add each as a separate WHERE clause
foreach(var f in filters)
{
    //this just adds to the existing expression tree..
    queryable = queryable.Where(u=>u.Name.Contains(f));
}
//this will actually hit the database.
var results = queryable.ToList();
```

This should generate *something like* this in SQL (entirely pseudo-code)

```
select 
  u.*
from 
  users u
where 
  (u.username like "%Sue%")
  or (u.username like "%Bob%")
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I was just about to post my own solution. Implemented exactly like this. But you had already posted it so will mark your answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
string filter = "alex, faheem, Cohen";
var filterArr = filter.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(f => f.Trim()).ToList();
var users = _dbContext.Users.Where(x => filterArr.Any(n => n.Contains(x.Name))).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**
For your requirement following query will work fine.

```
string filter = "Alex, faheem, Cohen";
var filterArr = filter.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(f => f.Trim())
            .ToList();
var users = _dbContext.Users
            .Where(x => filterArr.Any(n => x.UserName.Contains(n))).ToList();
```

If user has searched for "alex" and in Name (database column) there is "Alex Hales". `users` query will return the user "Alex Hales".

Comment: You misunderstood my requirement. If user has searched for "alex" and in Name (database column) there is "Alex Hales". Then as per your query still there will be no item in users

Comment: @Ahmad updated my answer, try now it will serve the purpose.